# Unable to send pdf attachment with form data using PHP

Tags: php

I have an .html form which requires data to be filled in and a .pdf attachment to be uploaded.  The .pdf and the data need to be sent via email.

The code I have successfully checks for the .pdf, but when I receive the email, the email is coming from one of our Apache mail server instead of the sender, the email is empty.. no form data and the attachment is stripped and replaced with a blank .txt

Can someone please look over my code and let me know what I'm doing wrong?  I'm not seeing it.

PHP code:

```
<?php

$fileInfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$fileMime = $fileInfo->file(@$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
if($fileMime == "application/pdf")
{
//Requestor
$requestor=$_POST["$requestor"];

//Requestor Phone
$telephone=$_POST["$telephone"];

//Requestor Email
$mail_from=$_POST["$req_mail"];

//Document Subject
$subject=$_POST["$subject"];

// Services Date
$req_date=$_POST["req_date"];

//Addintional Info
$info=$_POST["body"];

$email_to = "aaaa.aaaa@aaa.com"; // Who the email is too

$headers = "From: ".$mail_from;

$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
 $message . "\n\n";

 $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

 $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
 //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
 //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
 $data . "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

$message .="Request From: ".$requestor."\n"."Contact Phone: ".$telephone."\n"."Contact Email: ".$mail_from."\n"."Project/Mission Name: ".$subject."\n"."Need by Date: ".$req_date."\n"."Details: ".$info;

$ok = @mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 if($ok)
 {
    header("Form & attachment sent successfully");  
 } 
  else 
  {
  die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
  }
}
else 
{
header("Your attachment must be a .pdf");
}    
?>
```

and this is my .html:

```
<form action="sendreview.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">

<tr>
  <td width="40%">Requestor Name</td>
  <td width="2%">:</td>
  <td width="58%"><span id="sprytextfield1"><input name="requestor" type="text" id="requestor" size="50" /><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A name is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">A name is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="40%">Requestor  Number</td>
  <td width="2%">:</td>
  <td width="58%"><span id="sprytextfield2">
    <input name="telephone" type="text" id="telephone" size="50" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A phone number is required.</span>
    <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format 000-000-0000.</span></span>   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="40%">Requestor Email</td>
  <td width="2%">:</td>
  <td width="58%"><span id="sprytextfield3">
<input name="req_mail" type="text" id="req_mail" size="50" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">An email address is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">A valid email address is required.</span></span>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="40%">Project/Mission:</td>
  <td width="2%">:</td>
  <td width="58%"><span id="spryselect1">
   <select name="subject" id="subject">
     <optgroup label="TEST">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
     </optgroup>
   </select>
  <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="36%">Need by Date</td>
  <td width="2%">:</td>
  <td width="62%">
    <div id="OAWidget"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // BeginOAWidget_Instance_2443523: #OAWidget

    document.body.className += " yui-skin-sam";
    YAHOO.namespace("widget.Calendar");

    YAHOO.init_OAWidget = function() {
    var oCalendar_OAWidget = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("oCalendar_OAWidget","OAWidget", 
   {selected: "",
    mindate: null,
        maxdate: null,
        title: "",
    close: false,
        iframe: true,
        multi_select: false,
        navigator: false,
        show_weekdays: true,
    locale_weekdays: "short",
        start_weekday: 0,
        show_week_header: false,
        show_week_footer: false,
        hide_blank_weeks: false }
    );
    oCalendar_OAWidget.render();
    }
    YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(YAHOO.init_OAWidget);

    // EndOAWidget_Instance_2443523
      </script>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Message:</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><span id="sprytextarea1">
   <textarea name="body" cols="50" rows="4" id="body"></textarea>
    <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Attach File</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"> File type must be a PDF</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't build mime emails yourself. ALl of that mail-building code can be replaced with 4 or 5 lines of swiftmailer or phpmailer. Plus, your `header()` calls are totally wrong...

Comment: Thank you, I went back to using SwiftMailer and was able to get everything to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly getting values from $_POST.

Wrong:

```
$requestor=$_POST["$requestor"];
```

Right:

```
$requestor=$_POST["requestor"];
```

You should also be sanitizing and/or validating all inputs.

Comment: Thank you, I did notice that after I posted (D'oh!)  I want back to using SwiftMailer and was able to get everything to work.